# Why does this code give me a badbox?

Tags: indentation, minipage, warnings

Why does this code give me a badbox?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, notitlepage]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{1.0 \textwidth}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to understand the problem and not just fix it.

Comment: did not get any badbox. I am using winEdt 6.2 version. There may be problem of packages and Text distribution version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `minipage` of width `\textwidth` starts a new paragraph and therefore is indented by the amount of `\parindent` (15pt in `article`), so it spills over into the right margin by that amount. An easy fix is to add `\noindent` before the `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, notitlepage]{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent \verb|\parindent|: \the\parindent

\noindent aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

\begin{minipage}[t]{1.0 \textwidth}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{minipage}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{1.0 \textwidth}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]